# Requet Tracker RT4.4, Change Queue of existing ticket using REST API

Tags: rt

I am having two Queues Q1, Q2. User U1 has access to Q1 ad user U2 has access to Q2. Finally I have a ticket T whose owner is U1 in queue Q1.
I am logged in as U1 and want to change the ticket T1's queue to Q2 and assign it(change owner) to U2. And I want to use RT REST API to get this done in one operation of edit ticket. I have given all kind of access to U1/U2 user in their respective queues. But eveytime try editing the ticket with new queue(Q2) and new user(U2) I get exception/error message from RT stating "# queue: Permission Denied".
Any way I can achieve what I want or I am expecting something which is breaking very basic ACL of RT. Please help me understand this. 
How does the plugin "Extension - Queue Change On Update" works internally can any one help me understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have read the [REST API documentation](https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST) so you don't make any mistake by calling the proper commands. According to the description it seems to me that you don't have set the `CreateTicket` right of U1 in Q2 and vice versa. When you need U1 to change owner to U2 in target queue, you need also to set `ReassignTicket` right of U1 in Q2 and vice versa.

Sorry, I don't know the mentioned extension.